# Wait for an observable to retrieve data before executing another one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have these two http calls:

```
const newProject = this.newProjectForm.value;
newProject.stage = "In progress";

let newProjectFromServer: IProject;

this.projectService.addProject(newProject).subscribe((data) => {
  newProjectFromServer = data;
});

this.projectService
  .addEmployeesToProject(
    newProjectFromServer.id,
    newProject.assignedEmployees
   )
   .subscribe(() => {
     this.afterSubmit();
   });
```

The first one adds the project to the database so Spring apply an id to it, so in the data that i get as response it should now have an id.
Then i tried to add the array of assigned employees that i get from the form.
The problem is that the newProjectFromServer.id argument is undefined since i think it gets read synchronously

Edit: this is the addEmployeesToProject function:

```
addEmployeesToProject(
    projectId: number,
    employees: IEmployee[]
  ): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.httpClient.post<IEmployee[]>(
      `${this.baseUrl}/${projectId}/employees`,
      {
        _embedded: { employees },
      }
    );
  }
```

The Api result:

```
{
"_embedded": {
     "employees": [] // IEmployee[] array doesnt get save
   },
   "_links": {
     "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/26/employees"
     }
   }
 }
```

The add project request:

```
addProject(project: IProject): Observable<IProject> {
    return this.httpClient.post<IProject>(this.baseUrl, project);
  }
```

Comment: you can use pipe for this case, or move the addEmployeesToProject invocation inside of addProject subscribe and you will have access to the new project Id

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using the switchMap operator

```
this.projectService.addProject(newProject).pipe(
  tap(data => newProjectFromServer = data),
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.projectService.addEmployeesToProject(
    newProjectFromServer.id, 
    newProject.assignedEmployees
  )}
).subscribe((secondResult) => {
   this.afterSubmit()
});
```

I hope it helped.

Link for study purpose about the switchMap operator:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: thanks, but i did this and i get two errors: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)

Comment: You must type your service return calls, can you show me the code of your service too? I forgot to add the `return` on the switch map too. haha sorry about that

Comment: i edited the post with the add project request. the addEmployeesToProject is already in the post

Answer (score 0):

You can use **concatMap, switchMap, mergeMap**. **concatMap** is recommended as it makes sure the sequential execution of HTTP calls.

```
this.projectService.addProject(newProject).pipe(
  concatMap((newProjectFromServer) => {            
    this.projectService.addEmployeesToProject(
       newProjectFromServer.id, 
       newProject.assignedEmployees
    )}
).subscribe((secondResult) => {
   this.afterSubmit()
});
```

Comment: like the other guy who suggested switchmap this code gives me Argument of type '(newProjectFromServer: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>

Comment: Argument seems to be missing after `switchMap` in that case. Just compare it with my answer, you'll understand.

Comment: No i mean, i tried you're code.
I tried to give a type to newProjectFromServer : IProject or it would not recognize .id.
Either way i get an error similar to this: Argument of type '(newProjectFromServer: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.

Comment: As per you given code snippet, our solutions must work. I believe we need to see how you  have implemented `addEmployeesToProject` function.

Comment: i will edit the post now, the function return the added employee but it doesnt get persisted. Man i feel im doing something really wrong, it cant be this hard to do simple crud operations

Comment: edit looks okay. I wonder what is this error `(value: unknown, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>`. It has not nothing to do with shown code.

Comment: so i check on other questions and when this error is mentioned the answers always talk about adding a return statement. The quickfix from the IDE suggest me to either add a return statement that get placed before this.projectService.addEmployeesToProject(..) or to remove the body block brackets but i dont know if it works now.
edit: I mean i use the remove body block brackets and seems to work...man..

Answer (score -1):

I think a better approach will be, convert it into promise:

```
public async myFunc(): Promise<void> {
const newProjectFromServer = await this.projectService.addProject(newProject).toPromise()

await this.projectService
  .addEmployeesToProject(
    newProjectFromServer.id,
    newProject.assignedEmployees
   ).toPromise();
this.afterSubmit();
}
```

Comment: this seems to work fine the id is never null. let s see if i can do it with the switchMap now.